# Get multi dimensional array on dynamically created select2 multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to achieve a multi dimensional array using select2 multi-select like below

```
var options = [['20mg', '40mg'],
               ['Capsule', 'Tablet', 'Syrup'],
               ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']];
```

But I am getting the following output: [got this code from stack overflow]

```
["20mg", "40mg", "Capsule", "Tablet"]
```

Here's my code on jsbin https://jsbin.com/mayiza/edit?html,js,console,output

I am missing something. I have tried other method. But none of them is working the way I am looking for.

My code is:

```
var test = $(".attributeFormWrapper");
test.on("select2:select", function (event) {
        var values = [];
        // copy all option values from selected
        $(event.currentTarget).find("option:selected").each(function (i, selected) {
            values[i] = $(selected).text();
        });

        console.log("selected values: ", values);

});
```

Html Code for select2

```
<div class="attributeFormWrapper">
    <div class="attributeFormRepeat">
        <div class="col-md-12 select2Divs">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-md-11">
                              <label>Attribute (e.g. Color, Size, Stength, Type)</label>
                              <select class="form-control select2ProductAttribute commonSelect2" style="width: 100%;"></select>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-md-11">
                             <label>Attribute Value (e.g. Green, 20mg, Capsule)</label>
                             <select class="form-control select2AttributeValues commonSelect2" style="width: 100%;" multiple="multiple"></select>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>
```

Add New Attribute

Dynamically added select2 method below:

```
 function addrow() {

        var rowToBeCloned = $('.attributeFormWrapper .attributeFormRepeat:last');

        $(".select2ProductAttribute").select2('destroy');
        $(".select2AttributeValues").select2('destroy');


        var newrow = rowToBeCloned.clone();

        $(".attributeFormWrapper").append(newrow);

        selectAttribute();
        $(".select2ProductAttribute").last().val("").trigger("change.select2");
        selectAttributeValues();
        $(".select2AttributeValues").last().val("").trigger("change.select2");

    }
```

Button click event where I am adding select2 div

```
 $("#addAttributeDivBtn").click(function() {
        addrow();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an array, that looks like this:

```
var array = [
0: [ 'e1a' ,'e2a', 'e3a' ],
1: [ 'e1b', 'e2b', 'e3b']
];
```

But You are adding arrays like this:

```
var array = ['e1a','e2a',...'e1b','e2b'];
```

Try to get selected values separate, and then prepare an object or array way u need it.

Create empty array:

```
var array_empty = [];
var select1; // values from first select
var select2; // values from second select
array_empty.push( select1 );
array_empty.push( select2 );
```

Something like that :-) (writing from memory)

```
$('.select2-elem').each( function(i,e) {
    var values = $(this).val(); // getting selected values each of select element
    array_empty.push( values );

});
```

Comment: that's where I am stuck. How can I separate selected boxes and get values separately?

Comment: That's correct. But the fact is I am dynamically adding select2 divs. How can I track them and target them dynamically?

Comment: by class for example - $('.select2-elem').each( function(I,e) { });

Comment: I am using each function here like this   ' $(event.currentTarget).find("option:selected").each(function (i, selected) {
            values[i] = $(selected).text();
        });'

Comment: Can you show me a fully working example, please? I am stuck for around 5 days! Tried at least more than 6-8 ways. Nothing works. I was thinking about to put some index and target them but it seems clumsy and I don't know yet how I can implement that.

Comment: From your example I am getting 
:
["20mg", "40mg", "Capsule", "Tablet"]

Comment: Checking and trying to integrate your solution into my code. I will convey you soon.

Comment: It's working fine but when I am attaching this to the on change event to target dynamically added element, I need to get the value outside the scope! Trying to make it done. Let see.

Comment: I understand that u need to send this data, after all select are "selected" - yes ? If so - maybe u need to mark last select, and if last select is completed - run code. I think now you will drive down with Your problem. Sometimes brains are like windows :-P

Comment: @InsParbo Put whole code into one of this fiddles that works like now, and then it will be easier to find what went wrong. I think there is a little mistake in order of execution, that You are not seeing right now - this is normal in programming :-)

Comment: Here is my code https://jsbin.com/mayiza/edit?html,js,console,output :(